# interaction of three react components

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I would like to create a react app that looks like the one above where I have a list on the yellow component and when I click one item I pass the item to the green component that makes an API call to get some data that display and I have a button at the end that when I click it I pass the string of detail 1 to the component in orange that makes another API call and display the result. I was able to create such app but displaying the different components one after the other using the Link option and router. which means when the app start display only the yellow component, then when I click the link it displays the green one and when I click the button it displays the orange one. what I would like to have is the three components display at the beginning and then displaying the content when I do the click.

this is the code for the app with router and link

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import Left from "./Left";
import Top from "./Top";
import Bottom from "./Bottom";
import Right from "./Right";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Route path="/" exact component={Right} />
        <Route path="/Left" component={Left} />
        <Route path="/Left/top/:id" component={Top} />
        <Route path="/Left/top/:id/bottom" component={Bottom} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: forgive the right component

Comment: Instead of creating separate path for every component you can create a parent component which will have these three as child components and then they can interact with other through parent component

Comment: I did it like this ```
    return(
        <div className="wrapper"  style={{width:"800px", height:"600px"}}>
            <div className="left">
                <Left/>
            </div>
            <div className="up">
                <Top/>
            </div>
            <div className="down">
                <Bottom/>
            </div>

        </div>
    )

``` but if i use props in the child component they complains because i didn't pass yet. i pass when i click the link or button

Comment: You want to pass id of link from yellow component to green component, so what you can do is store the value you get from yellow component on clicking link in parent's state and pass that state variable through props to green component, also you can add a check in parent if value exist in that state variable only then render green component if you want empty space or you can handle this in green component as well

Comment: @AbhaySehgal yes this is the solution, you need to create a container that will render the three components and pass ids via props. For example, when you click on the yellow you will execute the function clickHandler of your container that will set the id that you need to pass to the green component, and you do the same thing for the orange and the green component.

Comment: thank you guys, how can i pass then.
this is should be in the yellow component?
 
const handleClick = (id) => {
< Top id={id} />
}
<div key={id} onClick={()=>handleClick(id)}>item</div>

Comment: following this video was really helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qf68sssXPtM